# Compare independent lines in two files

Tags: text-processing, diff

I have two files, each with 500k+ user accounts. I need to find the differences between the two (the missing accounts/delta). 
Each file is in a simple format, each line contains an email address in each file.

I have sorted by unique and alphabetical. Now need to find delta. Cannot figure out how to do this in Linux (Red Hat). Everything wants to compare line for line.

In `file1`:

```
user@email.com
user3@email.com
12343@email.com
blabla@email.com
```

on and on 500k accounts. In `file2`:

```
user@email.com
user1@email.com
user2@email.com
user4@email.com
bla1bla2@email.com
```

on and on 300k+ accounts. 
etc etc.

Comment: `man comm`​​​​​​

Comment: What does it mean to "compare contents to contents and output to new file"?  How is it different from "[comparing] line for line"?

Comment: and if your files are sorted, what is the problem with `diff` output ?

Comment: so if you have 500k lines in one and 398k lines in the other, both sorted alphabetical diff shows a difference with all because its just doing line by line. I need to ignore the matching accounts in both and output the unique.

Comment: You can use `grep`'s `-v` or `--invert-match` option along with the `-F` or `--fixed-strings` and  `-f` or `--file` options.  First find users in file2 not in file1: `grep -v -F -f file1 file2 > missing-users`.  Then find users in file1 but not in file2 and append to the same file: `grep -v -F -f file2 file1 >> missing-users`.  You could just as easily write the output of each `grep` command to separate files, then sort them together before combining into one file.

Comment: alternatively, use `comm -3` and `sed` (to remove the initial tab character from some lines), e.g.: `comm -3 file1 file2 | sed -e 's/^\t//' | sort > missing-users`.  Both file1 and file2 MUST be sorted before using `comm` like this.  The `grep` version works whether they're sorted or not.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, what you're asking for is exactly what [`comm`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=comm&sektion=1) does. Run `comm -32 file1 file2` to see the lines in `file1` that are not present in `file2`, or `comm -31 file1 file2` to see the lines in `file2` that are not present in `file1`, or `comm -3 file1 file2` to see the lines that are only present in one of the files, with the lines unique to `file2` indented by a tab.

Note that `comm` requires its input to be sorted. If you have already-sorted files, make sure that they're sorted *in the same locale*.